# Should R.java be placed under version control

Tags: android

Is R.java file generated by Android SDK on each compile or only when new resources are added using Eclipse? Do I need to put it under version control or not?

Comment: Both `gen/` and `bin/` folders should be ignored by whatever VCS you are using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `R.java` file is generated during resource compilation by `aapt` tool. You shouldn't add it to source control system.

Also, you should have noted the `gen` folder where `R.java` is placed. Your version control system should ignore this folder altogether, not only `R.java` file inside it. Because this folder is deleted on clean build (not sure about eclipse, but `ant` script definitely deletes it).

Answer (score 1):

When using Git to control Android projects I add

```
bin/*
gen/
```

to `.gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put it under version control. I think it's on each compile, one every new resource or clean up project.. but need to test to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have had projects with R in and out of source control.  Both worked.

Answer (score 0):

When the android SDK is loaded into eclipse, it will automatically generate the R.java file.  In older versions of the adt, having an incorrect R.java file would give an error, but I believe this is fixed now, and it shouldn't matter either way.  If you have the choice though, avoid checking it in.

I would add it to `svn:ignore`.

Comment: `R.java` is not generated when Android SDK is loaded into eclipse (actually its `ADT` which is loaded into eclipse), its generated as part of compilation of Android Project.